# How to use mutex to signal to producer process that consumer is done reading the resource

Tags: c#, mutex

I start two processes. One process will produce a resource, and the other will consume it.
I want the producer to wait for the consumer to be done reading before producing the next resource. The consumer process does not exist yet when the producer process starts. I assume that there is a way to do this using the Mutex class in C#. The problem is that as soon as I create a Mutex, the current thread owns it. Therefore if I call the WaitOne method, it immediately returns, but I want to wait until the consumer is done reading. If I open the same Mutex in another thread in the same process, I can now wait for it. Great, but now in the consumer process, I cannot signal when I am done reading because I cannot enter the synchronization context. The WaitOne method is just waiting for the other process to release the mutex.
Perhaps the Mutex class is just not the technology to use for this scenario?

Comment: Mutex are used when two consumers try to reach a shared resource so indeed it's not what you need in this scenario. Maybe MSMQ ?

Comment: Please, may you share what resource type is produced/consumed? Is it a file, a shared memory...?

Comment: You need to share your code, otherwise, it is hard to understand what exactly you need. So please share your code

Comment: There are built-in classes for what you want - Channel and at a higher level, the Datafllow classes like ActionBlock. MSMQ is for process-to-process communication, not pub/sub in the same application

Comment: You *don't* really need to share your code because you don't need a mutex for pub/sub if you use the built-in classes. No need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, is there a Channel implementation that can be used to communicate between processes, or would I have to make one on my own?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write such low-level code. .NET has built-in classes for this. At a higher level, the Dataflow classes like ActionBlock can be used for pub/sub in all .NET and .NET Core versions.

At a lower level, a [Channel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) can be used to implement exactly what you ask.

Both features allow buffering input and output messages, and setting a limit to how many items can be stored at a time. By setting the buffer limit to 1 you can get the behavior you want.

For example, you can [create a bounded channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel.createbounded?view=net-5.0) that accepts only one message at a time:

```
var channel=Channel.CreateBounded<MyMessage>(1);
```

A producer can write to the channel using a [ChannelWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelwriter-1?view=net-5.0) instance:

```
async Task Producer(ChannelWriter<MyMessage> writer,CancellationToken ct)
{
    while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await writer.SendAsync(new MyMessage(...));
    }
    writer.Complete();
}
```

A consumer can read data using a [ChannelReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1?view=net-5.0) :

```
Task Consumer(ChannelReader<MyMessage> reader,CancellationToken ct)
{
    return Task.Run(async ()=>{
        await foreach(var msg in reader.ReadAllAsync(ct))
        {
            //Do something with the message
        }
    });
}
```

A `Channel` can be cast implicitly to both a `ChannelReader` and `ChannelWriter`, allowing you to just pass the `Channel` instance to the producer and consumer :

```
var channel=Channel.CreateBounded<MyMessage>(1);
var cts=new CancellationTokenSource();

var consumerTask=Consumer(channel,cts.Token);
await Producer(channel,cts.Token);
```

Using a CancellationToken allows cancelling the producer and consumer

Comment: Unfortunately I need to stick with .NET Framework version 4.6.1, and I see that Channel came in version 5.0.

Comment: @4thex not at all. They're available as a multi-target [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Channels) that targets 4.6.1 as well

Comment: So it seems like I can just use NamedPipeServerStream and NamedPipeClientStream. I call WaitForConnection on the NamedPipeServerStream, and on the NamedPipeClientStream I call Connect. This seems like the simplest implementation.  
I need this to be inter-process, so Channel will not work for me. MSMQ seems too heavy for what I need to do. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like I can just use NamedPipeServerStream and NamedPipeClientStream. I call WaitForConnection on the NamedPipeServerStream, and on the NamedPipeClientStream I call Connect. This seems like the simplest implementation.